# Creating a Static Library - Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse

My project is ready for building and I'd like to generate some static .a files, so I go into the project properties and check the C/C++ Build Settings. Under the Build Artifact tab I have only the option to create either an executable or a shared library. The static option is missing.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: What platform are you using. And do you have all tools needed to created static libraries installed?

Comment: Have you got `ar` (`/usr/bin/ar`) installed?

Comment: The platform is Fedora 14, and I do have an archiver set up. My mistake was using the wrong toolchain. Selecting Linux GCC fixed it up. Thanks for the hints!